# Some Null values after applying pandas cut function to age variable(column)

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm hoping to turn a quantitative variable (age) to a categorical variable (agegroup).
But the issue is after applying pandas.cut, the agegrp column has some rows that are null.

Here "da" is a dataframe:

```
da['agegrp'] = pd.cut(da['age'] , [18,30,40,50,60,70,80])
```

The youngest age in my dataset is 18, and the oldest is 80; so I would expect that no rows in the agegrp column should be null.

I applied the following to make sure that there are no null values in 'agegrp':

```
pd.isnull(da['agegrp']).value_counts()
```

And got that

```
False    5602
True      133
```

Why is there some rows that are null even though the bins passed to cut cover all the possible values of age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the age should `int`, and `pd.cut` can pass `right` equal to `True` or `False` ,which mean they can only keep one close bin either left or right , in order to make it work we can do

```
da['agegrp'] = pd.cut(da['age'] , [17.9,30,40,50,60,70,80.1])
```

Comment: it totally worked thanks! but can you explain the reasoning behind why this worked a little bit more? I didn't quite get the reason

Comment: NVM, I totally get what you're saying now. the first range is (18,30] and the last is  [70,80) . thanks!